# OSQuery how can i retrieve Anti virus details?

Tags: osquery

i am new, and I am using osquery  to get specific list of applications installed on endpoint. doesn't seem like its possible, correct

Comment: What specific details are you looking for?

Comment: Anit virus or IM Chat applications ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look over the different tables available, here: https://osquery.io/schema/3.3.0

Depending on your platform, you should be able to pull a list of applications installed. For instance, on Windows, you can query the `Programs` table: https://osquery.io/schema/3.3.0#programs